Как повторить корзину в мобильном меню на сайте wordpress
Хочу повторить корзину в мобильном меню, но выдает ошибку что функция не может быть вызвана 2 раза - "Your PHP code changes were not applied due to an error on line 124 of file wp-content/themes/storely/woocommerce/cart/mini-cart.php. Please fix and try saving again.
Cannot redeclare woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment() (previously declared in wp-content/themes/storely/woocommerce/cart/mini-cart.php:124)"
Подскажите как можно реализовать. Нужно код со строк 21-24, повторить в строках 46-49


Переведите код ошибки на Русский язык, вы неправильно её поняли.

Измените в storely/woocommerce/cart/mini-cart.php:
Добавьте проверку на существование для функции woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment. В экшене storely_hdr_cart она как бы повторно объявляется, что вызывает ошибку. Только это файл основой темы - при обновлении правки могут слететь, поэтому лучше где-нибудь в дочерней дублировать и вносить изменения.
if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment' ) ) {

    function woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment( $fragments ) {
        ....
    }
}


Спасибо! Это работает!!!
